# How to use ng-show when a key with a certain value exists in an array?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

Let's say I have the following array:

*(it's made up, since I work for a customer who's data I can't post here)*

```
collections: {
    browsers: [
        {
            label: 'Chrome',
            visitors: 50,
            bounces: 23
        },
        {
            label: 'FireFox',
            visitors: 30,
            bounces: 15
        },
        {
            label: 'Internet Explorer',
            visitors: 60,
            bounces: 33
        },
        {
            label: 'Opera',
            visitors: 4,
            bounces: 2
        },
    ]
}
```

If I would like to show data for Chrome in my template, at the moment it'll be avaliable, I would normally use something like:

`<div ng-show="collections.browser.chrome">content</div>`

But since it's an array, this won't work.

---

Is there a way to use `ng-show` with the current object?

Comment: Yes, but you need to reference your object by either providing a correct Array index or converting your list to an object - if this is an option? (you would basically convert the data into this format when it arrives from the server)

Comment: Why not simply use a `ng-repeat` ?

Comment: @plamut This is how the data is delivered to me, and I'd rather not tinker with it, since I may break something else. And yes, I normally would've done that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
<div ng-repeat="browser in collections.browsers">
  <div ng-show="browser.label == currentBrowser">content</div>
</div>
```

And this HTML will be base on these values on your controller :

```
$scope.collections = //Your JSON Here
$scope.currentBrowser = 'chrome'; //Or whatever you want
```

Comment: Simple and clean, without extra controller/factory/service code.. I now kinda wonder why I never thought of this.. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> You can do something like this

controller

```
$scope.hasBrowser = function(name) {
    return collections.browsers.some(function(browser) {
        return browser.label === name;
    });
};
```

html

```
<div ng-show="hasBrowser('Chrome')">content</div>
```

=)

Comment: Nice trick, but I'd rather not use extra code in a controller at the moment. May use it in the future though, since I like your code!